# Dockerfile: Error parsing reference: \"openjdk:11-jdk-slim as build\" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, dockerfile, java-11

I am uplifting a java application to java 11 and getting this error when I try to start docker container locally.
I tried bunch of images but got the same error. I looked for this error but in some cases folks were missing organization in the image. Does anyone know what would be the right image I can use?

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim as build

COPY bo.zip /temp/summary/bo.zip
RUN cd /temp/summary/ \
    && jar xf bo.zip \
    && rm bo.zip
COPY maven /temp

FROM docker.abcd.net/some_project/jetty-debian10:9.4-java-openjdk11
COPY --from=build --chown=nonroot:nonroot /temp /opt/jetty-base/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running docker beta version. Issue resolved after upgrading docker (to docker desktop) on my machine.